# Is that possible that dispose all connections to SQL Server when session end method asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server

Is there any method to close/dispose existing SQL Server connections when users session end in ASP.NET, because I get that error I also use Entity Framework in my application

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: set in connection string Max Pool Size. generally do not let connection open. do your job and close it.

Comment: is there a limit of max pool size what is the max size of it

Comment: @Kostas I strongly advise against manipulating the max pool size - better to write code that closes (disposes) connections properly. Otherwise you are just delaying the pain.

Comment: @MarcGravell i have faced the same problem before and despite i am closing the connection every time my app connect to the db the problem remained until this change in connection string. Have any link to post to read about the possible problems? Thx in advance

Comment: thanks for your all advise I just put a try {conn.Open();}
finally{conn.Close();} in my code and became much better I believe

Comment: @Kostas then you've missed at least one connection. I have tracking code in my aoo that lets me track when a connection closes outside of where I expect it to.

Comment: @coolstaff in most scenarios, I would say that `using` is preferable to open/close

Comment: @ MarcGravell Thx a lot for your advice. Sorry but what is "aoo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, forget about sessions. Your connections should not be tied to the session at all - if they are, there is a problem. If the issue is that your EF contexts are tied to the session: then again, I'd say you're doing it very wrong.

There are (IMO) two reasonable scopes for connections in a web app:

- per call-site - i.e. where you obtain the connection whenever you need it (perhaps multiple times per request) and immediately dispose it before exiting the same method. This is usually achieved via `using` blocks.
- per request - where you hold the request open on the request and re-use it, then close / dispose it in the end of each request. This can be achieved using the global context and the end-request event.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session_End in Global.asax

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // End connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to keep the connection for a longer period of time and closing it at the end, you should open and close connections each time you need to do a job in SQL Server.

Connection pooling is efficient in modern databases and there is no need to try to keep connection open to long. This is especially true in situations like websites which won't scale well if you keep your connections open too long.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the pool of SQL Connections is exhausted (this is different from the app pool.) You can check that by [increasing the pool size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.71%29.aspx) through the connection string:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=northwind;Max Pool Size=100;
```